# Angular: set attribute data of HTMLs object

Tags: angular, typescript

I try to have a PDF viewer inside of a component.

For dynamically changing the PDF document within a sanitizer I need to set it by 
an attribute with [].

That is OK with img.

```
 <img src="assets/pic.jpg"/>
 <img [src]="'assets/pic.jpg'"/>
```

But NOT with object.

```
<object data="assets/test.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="300" height="200"></object>
<object [data]="'assets/test.pdf'" type="application/pdf" width="300" height="200"></object>
```

Why is that?

How can I set data dynamically as a result of a function.

Comment: You can try adding a *ngIf on the object element to show it when the URL is resolved and available.

Answer (score 1):

[Working Demo Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uxbno9)

You will need to sanitize and specify a SafeResource URL. See [here](https://angular.io/guide/security#xss)

```
import { DomSanitizer , SafeResourceUrl} from '@angular/platform-browser';

export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
   constructor(protected _sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

    get resolveURL() : SafeResourceUrl {
    // some logic to reolve and return the URL
    return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('https://www.orimi.com/pdf-test.pdf')
    }
}
```